# APACHE mod_auth limit number of users connecting at the same time

Tags: apache, mod-auth

im trying to password protect a directory and its files 
i know its possible to generate temporary download links with php
but the subfolders and files are generated dynamicly
its a little hard for me to use php. setting user/pass with mod_auth is Good but 
is there any way to limit the number of connections at the same time ? or log connections for each username somehow?
ex:

```
username:password :: 255.255.255.255 :: 2014/6/1
```

maybe another module can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make them FTP URLs and use a connection-limiting FTP server such as FileZilla Server.